# Twilio test SMS does not result StatusCallback

Tags: javascript, callback, sms, twilio

I noticed that when I send a test SMS with the Twilio API, everything works as described in the [documentation](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials) but the StatusCallback is not invoked by the system. The same setting works fine with the real credentials, I get the callback. Is this the expected behavior?

This is how I send the SMS:

```js
/* Test credentials */ 
var account_sid = "<<test acc>>";        
var auth_token = "<<test auth>>";
var fromNumber = "+15005550006"; // test number

var fromNumberEnc = encodeURIComponent(fromNumber); 
var toNumberEnc = encodeURIComponent(toNumber);
var textEnc = encodeURIComponent(text);
var body = "From=" + fromNumberEnc + "&To=" + toNumberEnc + "&Body=" + textEnc + "&StatusCallback=" + "https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftwiliocallback";
    httpRequest.post({
        url: "https://" + account_sid + ":" + auth_token +
             "@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + account_sid + "/SMS/Messages.json",
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: body
    }, function (err, resp, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rob from Twilio here.

Great question here on using Twilio's test credentials when building against the SMS API.  You are correct - StatusCallbacks do not fire for the Messages resource when invoked with test credentials.  The documentation section on StatusCallback you reference indicates that **the API response will return the value you set for the StatusCallback parameter when testing a *phone number purchase***, not creating a message or phone call.

I test for StatusCallbacks by mocking the StatusCallback request inside my test using the parameters from [the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon). The relevant parameter you want to test against on the new Messages resource is [MessageStatus](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-optional?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon).

Comment: Thanks! It's good to know. But actually, the StatusCallback is defined for all APIs, and as I explained, it works for real transactions. I guess, it would be good to update the documentation to explicitly indicate that it is not incidental that only the number purchase example has the StatusCallback listed.

Comment: Definitely agree - the reference here is just too obtuse.  Needs to be more explicit - appreciate that feedback.

Comment: Interesting, the value of the test credentials appears to be quite limited in that case.

Comment: I agree with aceofspades here that the value is pretty limited for things like testing the sending of SMS messages and testing the possible outcomes.  I understand you can mock the StatusCallback request, but then even if my tests work perfectly, I still can't say for sure whether this will work in a live environment as I might have mis-spelled something or something similar.  Basically it introduces human error rather than a start-to-finish test, including exactly what we would see in the StatusCallback for an actual failed SMS